# update column if the data is null by comparing all columns

Tags: mysql, null

i have encountered a scenario where i want to compare the columns which are null and update the data to that column which has the 1st occurrence of `null`  for example :

```
 id  institute_name_1  institute_name_2 institute_name_3 institute_name_4 
   1     xyz                  null          null             null            
   2     abc                  pqr           null             null
```

now if i want to update add the institute name of user 1 then it should be `update` on `institute_name_2` column and if user with id 2 wants to add institute then it should be updated on `institute_name_3`

Comment: Use `case .. when`. Show us your attempted query!

Comment: This is fairly bad table design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty bad table design.  Here is suggested version of your table, using the same data:

```
user_id | institute_name
1       | xyz
2       | abc
2       | pqr
```

That is, store each relationship between a user and an institute in a separate *record*.  Then, adding or removing relationships maps directly to adding or removing records.

If you really needed to keep track of which user/institute entry were first, second, etc., then you should probably have a dedicated column for that.  Perhaps a `time_inserted` datetime column would make sense:

```
user_id | institute_name | time_inserted
1       | xyz            | 2018-10-25 12:00:03
2       | abc            | 2018-10-25 13:55:23
2       | pqr            | 2018-10-25 14:02:00
```

Now the "second" institute for user #2 can be determined using the `time_inserted` column which provides an ordering.